# Proving the image of inner product map is whole subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I'm doing a specimen exam question and they often have typos and missed pieces of necessary information. I think the question I'm doing might be one such example, but am not sure:

We're given that $W$ is a subspace of a finite dimensional complex inner-product space $V$.

We're asked to prove that if $\left \{e_{1}, e_{2},..., e_{k} \right \}$ is a basis for $W$ and $\phi: V \rightarrow W$ is a linear transformation given by

$$\phi(v)=<v,e_{1}>e_{1} + <v,e_{2}>e_{2} + ... + <v,e_{k}>e_{k}$$

where $v \in V$. Then $im(\phi)=W$ and $ker(\phi)=W^{\perp}$.

I can't seem to do this without assuming that the basis is orthonormal. Do we need his be true?

Comment: The $e_i$ are linearly independent, so if a linear combination is zero then all the coefficients are zero, so all the $v\cdot e_i$ are zero, so $v$ is in $W^{\perp}$. Or was it the first half giving you trouble?

Comment: Yeah, it was the first half.

Comment: Why didn't you say so? There's no difficulty getting $v$ that's orthogonal to all the $e_i$ but one, and then just multiply that $v$ by the appropriate scalar to get that $e_i$ in the image.

Comment: How do we find such a $v$? Gram-Schmidt?

Comment: Well, you're changing the question now. All you need for the question is the existence of such a $v$. It exists because you can write down a homogeneous system of equations for its entries, with more unknowns than equations. If you actually want to compute $v$, then you could solve those equations, or do Gram-Schmidt, and there are other ways.

Comment: I still don't really see how we know such a $v$ exists. If we extend our basis of W to one of V and write $v=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}e_{i}$ as we've not been told anything about $<e_{i},e_{j}>$ for $i \neq j$ I don't see how we know one such $v$ must be orthogonal to all $e_{1}, ..., e_{k}$ except one?

Comment: $v\cdot e_1=0$ is a linear homogeneous equation in the unknown components of the vector $v$ (with respect to whatever basis you want for $V$). So is $v\cdot e_2=0$, and $v\cdot e_3=0$, and so on, up to $v\cdot e_{k-1}=0$. That's $k$ homogeneous equations in the $n$ unknowns, $n>k$, so there exists a nonzero solution.

Comment: Ah, awesome. Makes a lot more sense now - cheers!

Comment: Good. Write it up, and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $im(\phi) \subseteq W$.
We now extend $\left \{ e_{1},...,e_{k} \right \}$ to a basis $\left \{ e_{1},...,e_{n} \right \}$ for $V$ with $k<n. \\$
Consider $v_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}e_{i}$ such that $<v_{j},e_{i}>=\delta_{ij}$ where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta symbol.

This gives us $k$ equations and we have $n$ unknowns $(a_{1},...,a_{n})$ so there exists a nonzero solution $v_{j}$ for each $e_{j} \in \left \{ e_{1},...,e_{k} \right \}$.

If we now set $v'_{j}=\frac{1}{<v_{j},e_{j}}v_{j}$ then $\phi(v'_{j})=e_{j}$.

Therefore, $e_{j} \in im(\phi)$ for $j=1,2,...,k$.

So, any $(W \ni) \hspace{3mm} w=\sum_{i=1}^{k}b_{i}e_{i} \in im(\phi)$.

Which gives $im(\phi)=W$ as required.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, the image of $\phi$ is a subset of $W$ and $W^\perp$ is a subset of $\mathrm{Ker}\,\phi$. It remains to prove equality. If a vector $w\notin W^\perp$, then $\langle w,e_i\rangle\neq 0$ for some $e_i$. The independence of $\{e_i\}$ shows that $w$ is not in the kernel. So, $\mathrm{Ker}\, \phi=W^\perp$ and the dimension argument $$\dim \mathrm{Ker}\,\phi+\dim \mathrm{Im}\,\phi =\dim\,W+\dim\,W^\perp$$ together with $\mathrm{Im}(\phi)\subseteq W$ implies that $\mathrm{Im}(\phi)=W$.

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have mentioned that part 2 of the question asks us to prove that "hence" $V=W \bigoplus W^{\perp}$, so I don't think we're allowed to assume the dimension argument.

Comment: Well, you can show it differently if you know that the [Gramian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) $\langle e_i, e_j\rangle$ is regular, which is true (this is the matrix of the restriction $\phi|_W$ in the basis $\{e_i\}$ and if it has rank $\dim W$, then you are done). However, I think it's easier to first prove that $V=W+W^\perp$ directly and then use the dimension argument.